# How do you render a component within a partial in OctoberCMS?

Tags: php, components, octobercms, partials

In OctoberCMS, I am creating a component. In the component's `default.htm` partial file (`/acme/myplugin/components/mycomponent/default.htm`) I can include any other registered component by doing:

```
{% component 'someComponentName' %}
```

However if I have the following code to handle an AJAX request:

```
public function onAjaxRequest()
{
    return [
        '#ajaxUpdate' => $this->renderPartial('@dates-partial'),
    ];
}
```

and in my `dates-partial.htm` file I put the same contents as in my `default.htm` file, the `someComponentName` component is not rendered. I also tried putting the following at the top of the file:

```
[someComponentName]
==
```

however this is outputted directly as text to the page.

How can I have `renderPartial()` render a partial containing a component?

Comment: where from you are handling `onAjaxRequest ` ajax request. its bad practice to include component in other component's partial, instead you should use theme partial if you want to share code. once you nest component it will cause unexpected behaviour some-time it will work some time it will not.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya The `onAjaxRequest` is handled by my plugin's component. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "using theme partial". I put the partial in my theme's directory, but it still has the same behavior.

Comment: I have added my case where its working can you check it out of its same for you. and if you'r missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried your approach but seems its working for me. let me share howI did the things.

> My Page

```html
title = "compo-in-partial-in-ajax"
url = "/compo-partial-ajax"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0

[newCompo]

[newOne]
==
<!-- AJAX enabled form -->
<form data-request="onTest">
    <!-- Action button -->
    <button type="submit">Call Ajax</button>
</form>

<div id="ajaxUpdate">
Default content.
</div>
{% component 'newCompo' %}
```

> I have added 2 component

1. `newCompo` <- which is used to render content on page. basically in its 'default.htm' I added `{% component 'newOne' %}` so I am rendering another component inside.
2. `newOne` <- this is component which we are going to render inside our partial.

> this is my ajax handler

```php
public function onTest() {
    return ['#ajaxUpdate' => $this->renderPartial('@partial.htm')];
}
```

> `newCompo` component's -> `default.htm`

```html
{% component 'newOne' %}
```

> `newOne` component's -> `default.htm`

```html
<h1>Newone</h1>
```

> Partial file which is inside `components/newcompo` -> `partial.htm`

```html
<h4>partial</h4>
{% component 'newOne' %}
```

---

## Output

---

> **Normal**

[image]

> **After ajax Call**

[image]